# How to include erb file on another?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have template file .erb with HTML code inside.

How to include it in another file erb?

I tried to use `section` but this is not that I need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `render`:

```
<%= render('file_folder/other_file') %>
```

Note, that you can omit `.html.erb` part of the file name.

Comment: If ttemplat is located by path `/st/index.erb` how to set path in render?

Comment: @Daniel, `render 'st/index'` if it is from the other resource folder.

Comment: I get ` Missing partial statistic/_google_analitics.erb with`

Comment: @Daniel, 1. File name should be `statistic/_google_analitics.html.erb`. 2. You should use `render('statistic/google_analitics')`

Answer (score 0):

Following code work for me

```
 <%= render :partial => 'yourFile' %>
```